# how to specify the datetime format in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a file where each row has this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS  uint64 float64 float64 uint64
```

I've read it with:

```
pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0, names= ('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'), use_unsigned=True, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

The datetimes constructed are not correct.
Can I specify the exact format?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass a function that parses the correct format to the `date_parser` kwarg of `read_csv`, but another option is to not parse the dates when reading, but afterwards with `to_datetime` (this functions allows to specify a format, and will be faster than a custom `date_parser` function):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0, names= ('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'), use_unsigned=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```

Answer (score 9):

I have found this method.

```
f = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0, names= ('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'), use_unsigned=True, date_parser=f)
```

that worked

Answer (score 5):

**New shorter solution**

Since Pandas 2.0.0 there is a direct way to import dates with specific formats using parse_dates to specify the date-columns and date_format to specify the format.

**Example csv**

Based on your import I created the example file test.csv with the following content:

```
﻿datetime float_col int_col
2023-09-14-15-00-00 13.2 7
2023-09-14-15-12-03 13.4 8
```

**Direct one-line-solution - Import statement:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=' ', parse_dates = [0], date_format = '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
```

**Import result:**

[image]

Resulting dtypes:

```
datetime     datetime64[ns]
float_col           float64
int_col               int64
```

**Explanation**

parse_dates is a list of column positions with dates. Since the date column is at the 1st position. It is the position 0.
For date_format the usual Python format definitions are used.

Comment: When using this method, i get `read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_format'`

Comment: @thetangler Did you check your Pandas version? I wrote "since Pandas 2.0.0".

Comment: My version is Python 3. I’m assuming you meant that this method will work from Python 2 onwards?

Comment: @thetangler: No! It is about the "pandas" and not the "python"-version.