# How can i convert my date column to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have imported some data but the date column is in this format: 50:58.0, 23:11.0.. etc- when i click on the cell in excel however it is: 02/05/2019  07:50:58 (for the first one 50:54.0). So when i import into python as a pandas table it still retains the 50:54.0 format although i do not know why.

I tried changing the column to datetime as:

```
df['EventTS'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['EventTS'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

but it doesn't work the error is `time data '07:27.0' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)`

without changing format in excel how do i correct this issue in python?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28863313/8353711)

Comment: some data would be nice

Comment: How did you import? I'd expect 02/05/2019 07:50:58 to be 43501.3270601852 in Excel's format.

Comment: df=pd.read_csv('orders.csv')

Comment: Can anyone explain the format in the original post? How does 50:58.0 end up as 02/05/2019 07:50:58? What is the format?